# pandas version 0.16.0 after changing dataframe index all values become NaN

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am using ipython notebook and following pandas cookbook examples release 0.16.0. I have troubles when I am on page 237. I made a dataframe like this

```
from pandas import *
data1=DataFrame({'AAA':[4,5,6,7],'BBB':[10,20,30,40],'CCC':[100,50,-30,-50]})
```

then, i did this, trying to change the index:

```
df=DataFrame(data=data1,index=(['a','b','c','d']))
```

but what i get is a dataframe with all values being NaN!
Anyone knows why and how to fix it?
I also tried to use set_index function, and it gave me errors.

Thank you very much!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the index then either use `reindex` or assign directly to the index:

```
In [5]:

data1=pd.DataFrame({'AAA':[4,5,6,7],'BBB':[10,20,30,40],'CCC':[100,50,-30,-50]})
print(data1)
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
df.index = ['a','b','c','d']
df
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4   10  100
1    5   20   50
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50
Out[5]:
   AAA  BBB  CCC
a    4   10  100
b    5   20   50
c    6   30  -30
d    7   40  -50
```

I don't know if it is a bug or not but if you did the following then it would work:

```
In [7]:

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data1.values,index=(['a','b','c','d']))
df
Out[7]:
   0   1    2
a  4  10  100
b  5  20   50
c  6  30  -30
d  7  40  -50
```

So if you assigned the data to the values rather than the df itself then the df does not try to align to the passed in index

**EDIT**

After stepping through the code here, the issue is that it's using the passed index to reindex the df, we can reproduce this behaviour by doing the following:

```
In [46]:

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'AAA':[4,5,6,7],'BBB':[10,20,30,40],'CCC':[100,50,-30,-50]})
data1.reindex_axis(list('abcd'))
Out[46]:
   AAA  BBB  CCC
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c  NaN  NaN  NaN
d  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

This is because it enters the df constructor detects it is an instance of `BlockManager` and tries to construct a df:

Stepping through the code I see that it reaches here in frame.py:

```
        if isinstance(data, BlockManager):
        mgr = self._init_mgr(data, axes=dict(index=index, columns=columns),
                             dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
```

and then ends up here in generic.py:

```
119         def _init_mgr(self, mgr, axes=None, dtype=None, copy=False):
120             """ passed a manager and a axes dict """
121             for a, axe in axes.items():
122                 if axe is not None:
123                     mgr = mgr.reindex_axis(
124  ->                     axe, axis=self._get_block_manager_axis(a), copy=False)
```

An [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9951) has now been posted about this

**Update** this is expected behaviour, if you pass the index then it will use this index to reindex against the passed in df, from @Jeff

> This is the defined behavior, to reindex the provided input to the
>   passed index and/or columns .

See related [Issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9237)

Comment: @EdChum Regarding that last oddity, with which version of pandas do you get this result? With 0.16, I get exactly the opposite (first rows data, and the other three rows all NaNs). If you have this with latest pandas, please report an issue as this is definitely a bug.

Comment: @joris this is with version 0.16.0 numpy 1.9.1 and python 3.4.3 64-bit I'll post an issue on github

Comment: @Joris I think that last one is a mistake, I can't reproduce it and I think I must have ran some code exploratory code that had assigned to an intermediate df the index values ['a','b','c','d'] and then ran that last code snippet resulting in that result, I will edit this out to avoid confusion, thanks for alerting me

Comment: @EdChum ah, sorry, I meant the code that you removed that would be a bug and you could report. The initial answer (that you need to do `data.values` if you provide a new index/columns to `DataFrame(..)` is indeed expected behaviour

Comment: I am trying to reduce a `MultiIndex DataFrame` from Daily to Business Monthly (a subset of the frame).  I create a `DateTimeIndex` using `business_month_end_dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='BM')`. I then tried `converted = df.asfreq('BM')` and `converted = df.reindex(business_month_end_dates)` . All return `NaN`.  I then tried converted = `df.set_index(business_month_end_dates)` this returned `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2709 elements, new values have 127 elements` of which I understand.  Is there a function that allows a reindex and elimination of data?

Comment: @toasteez sorry but I can't debug a non-fully formed question, you should post a new question with raw data, code, and desired output. From what I understand you may find it easier to reset the index to a single level, then perform the `asfreq` or `reindex` first and then convert back to multi-index

Comment: @EdChum I've found the issue, my MultiIndex was an Index and the other was DatetimeIndex.  Changing these to both DatetimeIndex  allowed the use of `isin` against index, keeping the Multi-index as is.

Answer (score 3):

EdChum is absolutely right with the suggestion to use reindex, but I think what's happening here is that when you use a DataFrame as the argument for the data parameter, it uses the whole *existing* DataFrame when creating the *new* DataFrame.

If you want to accomplish what you're getting at, you need to explicitly feed the DataFrame class that actual *data* (not the data wrapped up in another DataFrame). You do this by using data1.values. You also have to explicitly give the class the column names, too, so it all comes out like so:

```
In [1]: pd.DataFrame(data=data1.values,columns=data1.columns,index=(['a','b','c','d']))

Out[1]: 
   AAA  BBB  CCC
a    4   10  100
b    5   20   50
c    6   30  -30
d    7   40  -50
```

Answer (score 2):

> also tried to use set_index function, and it gave me errors.

**Why did this happen?** `set_index` is for using one or more of the *existing* columns to set the index. So `data1.set_index('a')` would yield a `Key Error` as `a` is not a column in `data1`, whereas `data1.set_index['AAA']` would yield

```
     BBB  CCC
AAA          
4     10  100
5     20   50
6     30  -30
7     40  -50
```

The other two answers answer the rest of the Q.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df.index=['a','b','c','d']
```

This worked for me.